# zero to one with only one foreign key fluent mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-relationship, fluent

I have two classes

```
public class Foo
{
    public int FooId {get;set;}
    public virtual Bar Bar {get;set;}
}

public class Bar
{
    public int BarId {get;set;}
    public int? FooId {get;set;}
    public virtual Foo Foo {get;set;}
}
```

I'm using fluent mapping with Entity Framework. How can I map the Foo and Bar together so that I can have :

One **bar** and one or zero **foo**

One **foo** and one or zero **bar**

I think this is a correct schema for the 3rd normal form. I know how to do it if **Foo** had a **BarId** foreign key, but it is not the case.

Comment: You need to first know which of this entity will be the principal and which the dependent.

Comment: In this case both are equally principal, both can exist without the other

Comment: EF rule is to have a principal on one side :D

Comment: Then I thing you need to configure as two independent relationships. As @CodeNotFound pointed out one to one relationship one is principal and the other one is dependent, and both share the same PK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you are asking you will need to configure two different unidirectional relationships:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
            .HasOptional(s => s.Bar)
            .WithMany();

modelBuilder.Entity<Bar>()
            .HasOptional(s => s.Foo)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(s => s.FooId);
```